# Turn list of rules from radians to degrees, match all greek letters

Tags: replacement

Is there a easy way to match Greek letters only. I am trying to lower the angst of bachelors level students by keeping things as low level familiar as possible. Now understandably Mathematica counts things in radians rather than degrees. Not a big deal to me, but surprisingly big deal for the lower 1/3 in my classes. This distracts us form the issue.

So what i would want is to change:

```
a = {x -> 51.0169, y -> 51.0169, \[Gamma] -> 2.74159}
```

so that a is:

```
{x -> 51.0169, y -> 51.0169, \[Gamma] -> 157.082\[Degree]}
```

I can do somewhat like this:

```
Replace[a, Rule[\[Gamma], x_] -> Rule[\[Gamma], x  180/Pi ], 1]
```

this results in:

```
{x -> 51.0169, y -> 51.0169, \[Gamma] -> 157.082}
```

But id like the rule to do its magic irrespectively which  Greek letter it is. So essential rule **turn Greek letter rules to degrees**, but not normal Latin letters. Bonus would be to have the degree sign in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   greekdegrees = x_ /; MemberQ[ { γ , α }, x ] :>  Quantity[ x  /Degree , "Degree" ] ;

  { x , γ  } /. greekdegrees /. {x -> 51.0169, y -> 51.0169, γ -> 2.74159}
```

> [image]

Unfortunately the trig functions don't recognize the degree quantity, so to use it you'll need to do this kind of thing:

```
 Sin[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[γ]]]
```

Comment: ah that's quite well done. Ill wait a bit if you dont mind, if somebody is even better answer but i think this is it.

Comment: It looks nice , but I suspect you'll run into headaches carrying around the degree quantity.

Comment: Its no problem. No one longer going to calculate anything with it. Students are just using it to tabulate answers for themselves to measure real things and see how their solution matches reality.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
letters = Alternatives@@Map[ToExpression, CharacterRange["α", "ω"]];
a /. Rule[l : letters, x_] :> Rule[l, x /Degree]
```

> `{x -> 51.0169, y -> 51.0169, γ -> 157.082}`

The degree sign is equivalent to `Degree` in *Mathematica*, so the number will be converted back to radians if we put it in there. However if it's just for display purposes, as indicated by the comment below, then we may use it as a string:

```
a /. Rule[l : letters, x_] :> Rule[l, x /Degree "°"]
```

Comment: Thank youthat helps i ended up to this myself: `Replace[a, 
 Table[Rule[greek, x_] -> 
   Rule[greek, 
    x 180/Pi "\[Degree]"], {greek, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}}], 1]`

Comment: @joojaa I thought you were going to perform computations on the numbers, I added the string based solution for showing the degree sign to my answer. `Quantity` is better but that is already in george's answer now.

Comment: Thanks i got some ideas to finish my job turns out you terraced me 2 new things